# Their class has more singers than (we/us) -- possible syntactical derivations?

Tags: syntax, english, cases, pronouns, agreement

Forgive me if this is not the right sort of question to post here, but I was curious as to the derivation of the above sentence. (Apparently the correct choice is 'we').

```
Their class has more singers than we [have singers]
```

or

```
Their class has more singers than we [ do [have singers] ]
```

where [] denotes Ellipsis?

Comment: The title implies that you want to know if it's "we" or "us", but the body of the question is about something else.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to indicate that the given sentence was the topic of discussion, since it is what started me thinking, not just to focus on the choice between we and us. I'll change accordingly

Comment: By the way, I would claim quite strongly that the correct form is either "us" or "we do", but certainly not a plain "we".

Answer (score 4):

Since *we do* is equivalent to *we have singers*, there is no test by which it is possible to tell which of these is what is ellipsed.

(The correct choice became *we* when some grammarian decided a couple of hundred years ago that English grammar was supposed to be Latin grammar. The ordinary English has always been *than us*. The OED says " With a personal or relative pronoun in the objective case instead of the nominative (as if than were a preposition).This is app. the invariable construction in the case of than whom, which is universally accepted instead of than who. With the personal pronouns it is now considered incorrect.")

Comment: The *it* in the last sentence of the OED citation is confusing me.  Is *than we* now considered incorrect or is *than us* now considered incorrect?  (According to the OED, anyhow.)

Comment: The OED is saying that _than us_ was formerly normal (it has examples of _than us_, _than them_ etc from 1506 to 1861) but is "now" considered incorrect. I don't see a date on the article.

Comment: Dictionaries are not the places to go for grammatical information. Particularly when it involves whole constructions, like the comparative, which is quite possibly the most complex construction in English.

Comment: Is there any documentation from Old English on the topic?

Comment: @Jlawler: I take the point. But I don't know a grammar which makes a systematic attempt to date constructions, and what I was wanting to show was that the objection to _than us_ doesn't go back very far.

Comment: Oh, that's not my field at all. I don't pay any attention to peevers and zombie rules, let alone their history. You need somebody in historical peevolinguistics.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is with their *class* and not with them; therefore, the parallel for comparison is not our*selves* but rather our *class*. The correct finish, then, is "ours": "Their class has more singers than ours."

Comment: While I would also prefer to use "ours" if I were using this sentence myself, the OP asks about what is to be considered as the implied, unexpressed part of the sentence they gave. Saying "neither" would be an answer, for example, but I think saying that a different sentence is preferable to begin with, while possibly quite useful as a comment, isn't an answer in my opinion.